# Selenium Automation on IE11 (Enterprise mode)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have installed Enterprise mode on IE11 to support applications which are only run on lower version of IE. 
Using Enterprise mode on, to support application adhered to IE10 only I started scripting. 
I am successfully able to traverse few pages but at one particular sidebar I am not able to click element.
It gets highlighted using javascript which means I find the element. But I am not able to click the element. it gets dotted square around the element.
I don't get any exception on that line.
There are no frames issue.

P.S: One of the post stated that there might be an issue with unexceptional behaviour of Tomcat. Due to which I find element but click() event does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

If not working try:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```